# Azure Storage FileShare - logged operations not working for "Write" and "Delete"

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm attempting to monitor write and delete operations on a target fileshare. I've explored a few options and the only way forward is to use diagnostic settings to monitor the fileshare operations and send them over to an Eventhub - write and delete have their own event in a single eventhub namespace.

[image]

Here is the documentation from Microsoft on this approach. [Monitor Azure Files](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/files/storage-files-monitoring.md)

Each event message queue is monitored by an Azure Function Event Hub trigger.

The issue is both functions receive logs with categories "StorageWrite", "StorageRead" and never "StorageDelete" despite each function binding pointing to separate event names. Also the operation names are not the same in the documentation. I'm seeing "SetInfo", "Write", "Create" etc.

[Storage Analytics logged operations and status messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/storage-analytics-logged-operations-and-status-messages)

Has Microsoft changed their approach to logged operations for Fileshare? I'd like to note that I'm deleting and adding files to a mounted fileshare on my local machine.

Comment: Can you share your log details for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now resolved the issue. The connection string used by both triggers was specific to the "Read" event and therefore despite each trigger having their own unique event hub name within the function bindings they were receiving the same event logs.